# How to train api.ai/dialogflow chatbot dynamically?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to generate some "quick reply templates" i.e possible reply according to previous messages in a chat thread using Api.ai/Dialogflow.

I have trained api.ai agent to some extent to generate replies only for some selected queries. Now, I want to enhance it to generate replies for more queries but training an agent manually for a large number of queries is not practically possible. Is there any way to train the api.ai chatbot dynamically by analysing the previous chat thread, i already have stored in db or using the data of ongoing chats.

Users are some sellers so i assume they will talk regarding there product only, so questions will be somewhat similar in every chat thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a API for training.

If you have a log of the queries for your agent (via the API or your webhook), you could "train" your agent by using those log to determine the most common unanswered queries by looking at how many queries match the default fallback intent and create new intents and responses for those queries using Dialogflow's API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents#post_intents

Comment: This was correct at the time, but (per my answer below) the option for training via the API now exists.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there is now the ability to train via the API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/training, along with uploading text files with training lists.

> You can add more Training Phrases using the POST and PUT API methods for the /intents endpoint.
>
> Any changes made via the API to alter the agent's behavior, initiate the training in the same way when you save an intent. This trains the agent with the changes delievered through the API.